# drawBitmap at specific (x, y) point, Canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-canvas

Hi I have draw circle around arc by using below code, it is working perfect

```
    double x = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(45));
    double y = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(45));

    double x1 = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(135));
    double y1 = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(135));

    double x2 = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(225));
    double y2 = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(225));

    double x3 = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(315));
    double y3 = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(315));

    double x4 = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(0));
    double y4 = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(0));

    double x5 = radius + (radius)*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(180));
    double y5 = radius + (radius)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(180));

    canvas.drawCircle(getStartingDegree(), getProgressAngle(), 100, innerCirclePaint);

    canvas.drawCircle((int)(x-10), (int)(y-10), 20, finishedPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle((int)(x1-10), (int)(y1-10), 20, finishedPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle((int)(x2-10), (int)(y2-10), 20, finishedPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle((int)(x3-10), (int)(y3-10), 20, finishedPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle((int)(x4-10), (int)(y4-10), 20, finishedPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle((int)(x5-10), (int)(y5-10), 20, finishedPaint);
```

Screenshot is as below

[image]

but instead of circle if I use drawBitmap it is not perfectly showing

```
    canvas.drawCircle((int)(x-10), (int)(y-10), 20, finishedPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle((int)(x1-10), (int)(y1-10), 20, finishedPaint);
```

below drawBitmap should show at circle's position

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (int)(x-bitmap.getWidth()/2), (int)(y-getHeight()/2), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, (int)(x1-bitmap.getWidth()/2), (int)(y1-getHeight()/2), null);
```

screenshot is below

[image]

You can see that drawBitap should show at circle's position but it is showing above of small two circle

Comment: In the `drawBitmap()` calls, you're not calling `getHeight()` on `bitmap`.

Comment: Thank you so much, what a little silly mistake I have done

Comment: Now it is working perfect thanks a lot @MikeM.